# What does an NMOS transistor with the gate connected to the drain do?

Tags: nmos, programmable-logic

I'm studying about PLAs and I came across this simple PLA design.

What is the purpose of the highlighted transistors?

[image]

Comment: For reference, a transistor connected this way is often called a "diode-connected transistor". It's a more obvious where the name comes from if you're looking at BJTs instead of MOSFETs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are depletion-mode<sup>1</sup> NMOS transistors. They function as pull-ups or "loads" (effectively resistors) for the wired-NOR [NMOS logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NMOS_logic). When the source+gate connection is pulled low, they basically become current sources.

The key point is that pull-down (enhancement mode) transistors are placed at the cross-points in both the AND-plane on the left and the OR-plane on the right in order to implement the desired logic functions. The result is a direct implementation of a sum-of-products form of logic.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fomCEM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> As indicated by the fat "channel" line; an old shorthand notation. The other transistors in the diagram are the more familiar enhancement-mode devices.

Comment: Isn't that the digital symbol for a NMOS Transistor ?<br>
and we must complete the diagram, perhaps that's why it's missing the inverting buffers.
And can you explain a bit more.<br>
Thank you <3

Comment: No, the transistors at the bottom of the diagram without the fat "channel" line are the NMOS transistors. It's an old shorthand notation. Also, IIRC, there's something special about the doping of the PMOS "load" transistors.

Comment: Wouldn't the bulk connections be connected to VSS, and not to their sources as shown in your schematic?

Comment: @BrtH: Yes, that's a limitation of CircuitLab, which does not have a symbol with the substrate brought out separately. They also do not have a proper symbol for a depletion-mode device -- I had to fake it by drawing an extra line over the enhancement-mode symbol.

Comment: @DaveTweed Thanks for the confirmation, just wanted to check.

Answer (score 4):

To add to previous answer, reason is to use MOSFET as resistors caused that on IC level resistors are really space costly compared to good old MOSFET.
Compare size of 90nm PMOS and 500 ohm poly resistor on the picture. (90 nm ST CMOS tech)[image: Bottom is 90nm PMOS and bottom is a 500 Ohm poly resistor.]